# Laplace Transform Issues and Inutition

Tags: laplace-transform

FYI I am an engineering student and would like to refrain from very complex notations. I am simply looking for a more accurate understanding of the laplace transform which is not an algebraic definition.

From my understanding for any function $f(t)$ we can express it via $\int(f(t)*e^{-st}))|[\infty,0]$. This provides some function $F(s)$ which is always a ratio of the zeros of F(s) by the poles of $F(s)$.

My main question is with any plotter online or simply plotting the $F(s)$ vs $s$, $s$ is noted as a one-dimensional axis but by definition, $s$ should be a combination of real and imaginary components $(\sigma + i*\omega)$. For example, if we have $F(s) = 1/(s^2+2s)$ and we were to plot $1/(x^2+2x)$ on Desmos would the x-values represent simply |real component| + |imaginary component|? or the square root sum of components? or simply the imaginary or real, etc.

I have also been curious about the idea that they always talk about the laplace transform moving a function from the time domain to the frequency domain. Why is this the case and how do we know this?

I have also been attempting to gain some intuition to understand how I can apply the laplace transform to a function via. a spring mass system analogy. I have been using this analogy since it seems to be popular and has applications between frequency and the $f(t)$ of the mass' motion. In these examples, we have an ODE representing the equation of motion and would usually solve $f(t)$ by guessing a solution in the form $e^{mt}$. There is some link when the laplace transform is done of the problem where the locations where $s>\infty$ is the same as the $m$ values of our solution. One thing to note is that the real part of $s$ should be analogous to the rate of exponential decay/growth of the mass oscillation. Whereas the imaginary part represents the natural frequency of oscillation.

-
{
The idea I have come up with is for the function being $f(t) = m*t'' +ct' +kt -$ Forced($t$).
If we take the laplace transform of both sides, $f(t)$ can be represented as an additional forcing function of time. This would mean that our resulting function $F(s)$ could be viewed as the resulting (real and complex frequency) (s) and measure of amplitude ($y$-axis) of an additional force on the system needed for the equation to be true. }

-

Yeah honestly I thought I was getting somewhere with this but I'm really confused. If anyone has any intuition or a good analogy to explain what this is similar to it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Wanting to understand these concepts rather than just applying them to problems is understandable but your question is too broad. As it stands, someone would have to write a paper on the Laplace transform which would probably be no clearer than what would turn up on an internet search. You should focus your question to a specific aspect of the Laplace transform. You could certainly post more questions as your understanding deepens.

Comment: This recent post from mathoverflow may be of some help https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464191/motivation-and-physical-interpretation-of-the-laplace-transform

Comment: A long winded answer to one of your questions: In many situations, the Laplace transform of $f$, call it $\hat{f},$ is analytic on the set of $s \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\operatorname{re} s \ge 0$. The values of an analytic function on a fairly small set of values (see the identity theorem) is sufficient to completely define the function. In particular, the behaviour of $\hat{f}$ on the positive real axis are sufficient to characterise $\hat{f}$ more generally.